# Symfony2 working with multiple applications

Tags: php, symfony

I have different projects, they all include a bundle that i wrote.

Each project (application) can have different custom bundles so not all bundles are shared.

Is there an easy way that both projects dont know each other but still have the same shared bundle?

Update:
A shared bundle is actually a common bundle, i use this bundle in multiple projects, on different servers.

Comment: what do you mean by "shared bundle"? could you please elaborate your understanding of a "shared bundle" a bit more detailed? a symlink on the server?

Comment: I updated my original post, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If 'shared' means 'only one folder in filesystem then use symlinks
  (ln -s)
- If 'shared' means the same bundle use composer.json to define which
  bundles to use (you can use [Satis](http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md) to manage private bundles)

Comment: I think your first solution is the best, however i still have duplicate code when i want to keep projects in there own git (because of the common bundle)